# Speeding up exact evaluation of an integral with non-constant limits?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I am working on a problem that has as part of its result an integral of the form

> $\text{Integrate}\left[c,\left\{x_1,0,m_1\right\},\left\{x_2,x_1,m_2\right\},\text{...},\left\{x_n,x_{n-1},m_n\right\}\right]$

where

> $m_1<=m_2<=... m_{n-1}<=m_n$ and $n>50$, all $m_x$ are non-negative rationals,  with $c$ a rational non-negative constant.

So each subsequent integration limit has a lower limit equal to the prior limit's value.

I can evaluate this acceptably quickly using `NIntegrate` with `AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo` as the method, but I'd prefer if possible to get exact results.

Evaluation of the exact result takes a torturous amount of time as written above. 
Is there a technique to speed this up in Mathematica?

A small runnable (in reasonable time) example:

```
Integrate[1, {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, x1, 4}, {x3, x1, 6}, {x4, x1, 8}, {x5, 
  x1, 10}, {x6, x1, 12}, {x7, x1, 14}, {x8, x1, 16}, {x9, x1, 
  18}, {x10, x1, 20}, {x11, x1, 22}, {x12, x1, 24}, {x13, x1, 
  26}, {x14, x1, 28}, {x15, x1, 30}, {x16, x1, 32}, {x17, x1, 
  34}, {x18, x1, 36}, {x19, x1, 38}, {x20, x1, 40}, {x21, x1, 
  42}, {x22, x1, 44}, {x23, x1, 46}, {x24, x1, 48}, {x25, x1, 
  50}, {x26, x1, 52}, {x27, x1, 54}, {x28, x1, 56}, {x29, x1, 
  58}, {x30, x1, 60}, {x31, x1, 62}, {x32, x1, 64}, {x33, x1, 
  66}, {x34, x1, 68}, {x35, x1, 70}, {x36, x1, 72}, {x37, x1, 
  74}, {x38, x1, 76}, {x39, x1, 78}, {x40, x1, 80}, {x41, x1, 
  82}, {x42, x1, 84}, {x43, x1, 86}, {x44, x1, 88}, {x45, x1, 
  90}, {x46, x1, 92}, {x47, x1, 94}, {x48, x1, 96}, {x49, x1, 
  98}, {x50, x1, 100}]
```

This takes a couple of seconds on my machine, the `NIntegrate` version takes a few hundredths of a second. I'd be pleased getting the exact result in a few tenths of a second if possible.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion) and [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure). First, convert your variable ranges to an [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
intervals = {
    {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, x1, 4}, {x3, x1, 6}, {x4, x1, 8}, {x5, x1, 10},
    {x6, x1, 12}, {x7, x1, 14}, {x8, x1, 16}, {x9, x1, 18},
    {x10, x1, 20}, {x11, x1, 22}, {x12, x1, 24}, {x13, x1, 26},
    {x14, x1, 28}, {x15, x1, 30}, {x16, x1, 32}, {x17, x1, 34},
    {x18, x1, 36}, {x19, x1, 38}, {x20, x1, 40}, {x21, x1, 42},
    {x22, x1, 44}, {x23, x1, 46}, {x24, x1, 48}, {x25, x1, 50},
    {x26, x1, 52}, {x27, x1, 54}, {x28, x1, 56}, {x29, x1, 58},
    {x30, x1, 60}, {x31, x1, 62}, {x32, x1, 64}, {x33, x1, 66},
    {x34, x1, 68}, {x35, x1, 70}, {x36, x1, 72}, {x37, x1, 74},
    {x38, x1, 76}, {x39, x1, 78}, {x40, x1, 80}, {x41, x1, 82},
    {x42, x1, 84}, {x43, x1, 86}, {x44, x1, 88}, {x45, x1, 90},
    {x46, x1, 92}, {x47, x1, 94}, {x48, x1, 96}, {x49, x1, 98},
    {x50, x1, 100}
};

reg = ImplicitRegion[
    Evaluate[And @@ Replace[intervals, {a_, l_, r_} -> l < a < r, {1}]],
    Evaluate[Cases[intervals, _Symbol, Infinity] //Union]
]
```

> ImplicitRegion[
>    0 < x1 < 2 && x1 < x2 < 4 && x1 < x3 < 6 && x1 < x4 < 8 && x1 < x5 < 10 && 
>     x1 < x6 < 12 && x1 < x7 < 14 && x1 < x8 < 16 && x1 < x9 < 18 && 
>     x1 < x10 < 20 && x1 < x11 < 22 && x1 < x12 < 24 && x1 < x13 < 26 && 
>     x1 < x14 < 28 && x1 < x15 < 30 && x1 < x16 < 32 && x1 < x17 < 34 && 
>     x1 < x18 < 36 && x1 < x19 < 38 && x1 < x20 < 40 && x1 < x21 < 42 && 
>     x1 < x22 < 44 && x1 < x23 < 46 && x1 < x24 < 48 && x1 < x25 < 50 && 
>     x1 < x26 < 52 && x1 < x27 < 54 && x1 < x28 < 56 && x1 < x29 < 58 && 
>     x1 < x30 < 60 && x1 < x31 < 62 && x1 < x32 < 64 && x1 < x33 < 66 && 
>     x1 < x34 < 68 && x1 < x35 < 70 && x1 < x36 < 72 && x1 < x37 < 74 && 
>     x1 < x38 < 76 && x1 < x39 < 78 && x1 < x40 < 80 && x1 < x41 < 82 && 
>     x1 < x42 < 84 && x1 < x43 < 86 && x1 < x44 < 88 && x1 < x45 < 90 && 
>     x1 < x46 < 92 && x1 < x47 < 94 && x1 < x48 < 96 && x1 < x49 < 98 && 
>     x1 < x50 < 100, {x1, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x2, 
>     x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x3, x30, x31, x32, x33, 
>     x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39, x4, x40, x41, x42, x43, x44, x45, x46, x47, 
>     x48, x49, x5, x50, x6, x7, x8, x9}]

Now, use [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure):

```
res = RegionMeasure @ reg; //AbsoluteTiming
res
N @ res
```

> {2.09289, Null}
>
> 2965552832547973527300539562780813113506017776171989352778554799616984916548386816/325
>
> 9.12478*10^78

Compare to the numerical answer:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, x1, 4}, {x3, x1, 6}, {x4, x1, 8}, {x5, 
x1, 10}, {x6, x1, 12}, {x7, x1, 14}, {x8, x1, 16}, {x9, x1, 
18}, {x10, x1, 20}, {x11, x1, 22}, {x12, x1, 24}, {x13, x1, 
26}, {x14, x1, 28}, {x15, x1, 30}, {x16, x1, 32}, {x17, x1, 
34}, {x18, x1, 36}, {x19, x1, 38}, {x20, x1, 40}, {x21, x1, 
42}, {x22, x1, 44}, {x23, x1, 46}, {x24, x1, 48}, {x25, x1, 
50}, {x26, x1, 52}, {x27, x1, 54}, {x28, x1, 56}, {x29, x1, 
58}, {x30, x1, 60}, {x31, x1, 62}, {x32, x1, 64}, {x33, x1, 
66}, {x34, x1, 68}, {x35, x1, 70}, {x36, x1, 72}, {x37, x1, 
74}, {x38, x1, 76}, {x39, x1, 78}, {x40, x1, 80}, {x41, x1, 
82}, {x42, x1, 84}, {x43, x1, 86}, {x44, x1, 88}, {x45, x1, 
90}, {x46, x1, 92}, {x47, x1, 94}, {x48, x1, 96}, {x49, x1, 
98}, {x50, x1, 100}]
```

> 9.15451*10^78

Since the numerical answer uses MonteCarlo methods, it fluctuates every time it is evaluated.

**Addendum**

For this particular integral, all of the integration variables depend on the first integration, so you can just do:

```
Integrate[Times @@ (Range[4, 100, 2] - x), {x, 0, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.254912, 2965552832547973527300539562780813113506017776171989352778554799616984916548386816/325}

Comment: +1 for interesting idea. This however takes about the same time (within a few tenths) of 2+ seconds. I'm curious what the timing is on my example in your environment: my laptop is no slouch, I find it hard to fathom your environment is nearly 1000x faster.

Comment: @ciao It takes about the same amount of time as yours. I think it is possible to come up with a symbolic result, and avoid integration entirely. Would that be better?

Comment: A symbolic result could be interesting - but I'm still curious about the timings, unless I'm misreading your post & comments: On my machine, my integral and the regionmeasure results take ~2 seconds, but on your environment, the integral takes ~2 seconds but the regionmeasure takes ~0.03 seconds? Is that correct?

Comment: @ciao I see your question. It gets cached, so I must have put in the cached result by mistake. The first time it executes it takes ~2 seconds, but the second time it is much faster.

Comment: Your observation in the addendum does the trick. Accepted, and thanks!

Comment: As an aside, using your observation and adding a precalculating and expanding of the integrand outside of the integral speeds things up dramatically - the exact integral ends up being faster than numeric integration. Thanks again, Carl!

Answer (score 2):

To make comparable timings, the definition of the [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) should be included in the timing of the [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) approach.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

$HistoryLength = 0;

res1 = N[Integrate[1, 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{x[k], x[1] (1 - KroneckerDelta[k, 1]), 2 k}, {k, 50}]]] // 
  AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.89516, 9.12478*10^78} *)

res2 = Module[{reg = 
     ImplicitRegion[
      And @@ Table[x[1] (1 - KroneckerDelta[k, 1]) < x[k] < 2 k, {k, 50}], 
      Evaluate@Array[x, 50]]},
   RegionMeasure[reg] // N] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.47009, 9.12478*10^78} *)
```

`Integrate` is about `17%` slower than `RegionMeasure`

```
res1[[1]]/res2[[1]]

1.17208
```

The results are identical

```
res1[[-1]] === res2[[-1]]

(* True *)
```